# What cycling equipment would you give as a Christmas gift?

Tags: shopping, equipment

I want to buy a cycling equipment to my friends, he like cycling, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have been given cycling stuff for presents over the years, unless I had asked for it, most I never used.  A keen cyclist is usually kitted out with all they want, and no keen cyclists carries more than they want on a ride. Ask what if they want anything before buying it, or a voucher from a bike shop.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not give them a "gift certificate". Money from a recognized government is a negotiable instrument. The funny money that every entity is eager to sell you is worth _nothing_, until it is exchanged for goods. If you really can't decide, choose anything, and enclose a gift receipt (which doesn't immediately reveal the value, but which enables the recipient to exchange the item with something else of their choosing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the riding conditions of course but the following small items can usually be as cheap or as expensive as required and it is always possible to say a spare will not do harm and are not so specific that you may not fit the preferences of the cyclist or even specs of the bicycle:

- Gloves (for riding outside hot summer). They get wet in a rain, a second pair will not do harm. Also thinner/thicker, the current air conditions depending.
- Cap for wearing under helmet, same
- Glasses, if the corrective optics is not needed or can be fitted. Vital against bugs if they happen on the way, also if the sun is very bright.
- Small clip-up rear light (for emergency, even if there is main rear right already).
- Light reflectors, even more important if the cyclist seldom rides in the night (when will happen, likely to be no lights ready)
- Tubes are in a good price range and are replaced in somewhat yearly basis, but you need to match the diameter, width and preferred type of the valve. Diameter and width may be printed on the tire from outside where you can read them. You can still buy something more expensive than typical to make it an interesting gift.
- A bottle for a drink, if mountable (complete with mounting kit if not already present). You may ask in the shop if the bottle is mountable, pointing to the similar bicycle that is there for sale.

Parts like lock, primary lights, pump, helmet or cycling computer may depend too much on what the cyclist really likes and wants to use, and good versions of them easily go over the upper price range. They may still be an option if you know cyclist owns none.

Answer (score 3):

If your friend is a dedicated cyclist, finding a good gift will be very complicated, there's a huge risk of having this gift taking dust.

If you can't know directly or indirectly (by asking the riding buddies for instance), a voucher for an online store seem to me the best option. I know in some cultures, giving "money" is not acceptable, but here are some arguments:

- enthusiasts are usually very opinionated about what they like/don't like, so you'll be sure that the voucher will be used for things they appreciate
- a dedicated cyclist has probably everything they need, so the gift won't be redundant
- it can help finance something that your friend wants to buy, but that might be a bit out of his and your budget

Comment: Wow, your comments are very good, I will take your comments into consideration, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I find that food is a great choice.  I've discovered several different new foods this way.

- Mint cake
- Bliss balls
- Lime juice in drinking water

It's also thoughtful without being expensive.

Comment: For the food, he prefers the equipment for the cycling.